# Blender Add On : "Measureit", the measurement line generated are diagonal

Tags: python, add-on

referring to the title, the line generated using the Measureit add on are diagonal. The following image below are from my scene
[image]

Blend file of the model.

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I think he wants the measureit blue lines to be perpendicular to the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the advanced options, deactivate *Automatic position* and choose *X > 0*:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, that what I am looking for.